# Content Property error on confluence cloud error

Tags: json, confluence, node.js-addon, confluence-rest-api

i am developing an addon on confluence cloud and i needed to store a value .i am persuing this tuto in the link bellow https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/modules/confluence/content-property.html 
after declaring this value "ideation " in section "confluenceContentProperties" in my descriptor json file, i get this error in my console

The add-on descriptor failed to validate against the schema. Please confirm this add-on is intended for use with Confluence and then contact the add-on vendor.
/confluenceContentProperties/0: object has missing required properties (["key"])

Answer (score 0):

You also need to update `atlassian-connect.json` file and ensure that the values are correct. You can also validate your `json` file with [this validator](https://atlassian-connect-validator.herokuapp.com/validate).